# Cannot import sample data magento 1.9 phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

I'm new to magento.

I need to first install sample data. I created an empty database with phpmyadmin and then I imported magento_sample_data_for_1.9.1.sql file, but this throw me so many errors.

I'm following tutorials on youtube, I can't see this same error in any site, please if anyone know. Thank you so much.

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbBEG.jpg)

EDIT FOR MORE INFO:

I'm trying to import magento sample data to a empty database (I read than I need to install it first, and then install magento), following tutorials, all steps are like this:

1) Download sample data done!
2) Create a new empty database. I'm doing it with phpmyadmin.
3) Import the sample data .sql and this should create all the tables from that file, but give me instead 124 errors.

I'm trying to install it on local, using WAMP.

I really need this because is for a job, I dont know because all the videos, all the tutorials are that exact steps to import the sample data to en empty database.

this is a tutorial reference: https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento/install-magento-sampledata

Anyone have similar issues? Any doubt of what I'm doing please let me know, and I tell you.

SOLUTION: Ok, the community is not that kindly. I've come with the solution. 
phpmyadmin have some troubles reading .sql magento sample data so I used the SQL command line to import the .sql I needed, and it work that way.

Thank you, anyway! and if anyone pass though this problem, this is the solution.

Comment: OK -- Help us help you ....  What is the error?  Are you sure the data is THERE?  There are more questions that need answered before ANYONE can help you ..  Please elaborate and make some effort in asking your question...

Comment: the errors:

214 errors were found during analysis.

Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 709240)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "UNLOCK" at position 56679)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 57631)

Comment: You can import database using cmd. If your `sql` file is well that will work for sure. Just google it "How to import database using cmd". You can do it don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

First download fresh magento sample data from [Download magento sample data](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)

You can create new empty database in phpmyadmin and also follow below steps

1. Open your Xampp/Wamp php.ini file and edit below thing:

   max_execution_time=18000

   max_input_time=18000

   post_max_size=1024M

   upload_max_filesize=1024M

After all thing then save php.ini file and restart your Xampp/Wamp.

Now you can try to import sample data in phpmyadmin.

It's working fine....

Comment: Yes it's best solution.